# Is there a way to place a prepended a select menu beside a standard text input?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am getting started with JQueryMobile and love it. I am wondering if there is a way to place a prepended a select menu beside a standard text input.

For example, if the text input were to be for a name, then the prepended select would contain Mr, Mrs, etc.

### Edit 1:

I've looked at the [control group docs](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/controlgroups/) and for a case like buttons it works e.g.

```html
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext">Icon only</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext">Icon only</a>
</div>
```

However if I use an input like

```html
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext">Icon only</a>
    <input type = "text" name = "some_input" id = "some_input">
</div>
```

It gives a weird result with the input overlapping the button.

### Edit 2:

I've looked at [grids](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/content/content-grids.html) but cannot see a way to have a div span 2 grids. e.g.

```html
<div class="ui-grid-b">
<div class="ui-block-a">Block A</div>
<div class="ui-block-b ui-block-c">Block C</div>
</div>
```

I've tried the above, but it doesn't work as desired, for example

```html
<div class="ui-grid-c">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
        <label for = "full_name">
            Name
            <select id = "honorific" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">
                <option value = "mr">Mr</option>
                <option value = "mrs">Mrs</option>
                <option value = "miss">Miss</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-block-b ui-block-c ui-block-d">
        <input type="tel" data-clear-btn="true" id = "full_name" name = "full_name">
    </div>
</div>
```

simply yeilds the select box below the full name label, and the input only spans what appears to be one cell/block - rather than the 3 cells/blocks of the grid.

Comment: Use girds http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/content/content-grids.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Omar. I've had a look at grids but couldn't find a way to make it work - detailed in edit 2 above.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen control group works best with buttons, check boxes, etc. Not with the combination you're expecting to do. So here are two solutions for you.

### Without using grids

You'll just have to make the two elements as an *inline-block*, like this :

```
.ui-select, .ui-input-text {
    display:inline-block
}
```

**<kbd>[Demo with No grids, No control group.](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/vBxMa/4/)</kbd>**

### Using grids

The way you're using grids is wrong. You'll have to use *two-column* grid, which will have these two two classes alone: **ui-block-a & ui-block-b**, like this :

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
  <div class="ui-block-a">Block A</div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">Block B</div>
</div>
```

This will scale your markup accordingly. Here's how the HTML looks like :

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
  <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:100px">
    <select name="select-choice-min" id="select-choice-min" data-mini="true">
       <option>Mr.</option>
       <option>Mrs.</option>
       <option>Ms.</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Enter Name" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**<kbd>[Demo with grids](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/vBxMa/5/)</kbd>**

Comment: Hi @hungerpain - thank you for taking the time to respond. I've edited your without grids example http://jsfiddle.net/vBxMa/7/ to include the fieldcontain div and label for the input which I believe jqm say is best practice and it seems to break. It breaks. Ideally what I'd like is the label on the left and the select&input on the right - it seems like the grid option you propose above is likely to be the best bet - though I'll need to play with it.